# Null coalescing operator in shell for an expression var=${`expression`:-$var}

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, sh

I am looking to a way to leverage null coalescing feature that exists in other language for my script but I can't seem to wrap my expression to  accept the first non null value from an expression and a variable in a one line .

**Context**

I need to check the list of specific inbound open ports from my azure network security group but there are two sources where ports can be defined (all port in one rule [22,80,etc} or one port per rule [rule1=22 , rule2=80 etc])

To make this simple  :

I have two variables and they store list of ports in a vertically (Array).how I get the values doesn't matter

- $nsg_port_a  (ports found on multiport rules)
- $nsg_port_b  (ports found on all single port based rules)

```
nsg_port_a=$(az network nsg show -g $My_resourceG -n $My_SG --query securityRules[?direction==\`Inbound\`].destinationPortRange -o tsv)
nsg_port_b=$(az network nsg show -g $My_resourceG -n $My_SG --query securityRules[?direction==\`Inbound\`].destinationPortRanges[] -o tsv)

  # echo $nsg_port_a
  22 80 443
  # echo $nsg_port_b
  80 443
```

-I just need to confirm for example that port 22 occurs once in either variables.

- i.e if 22 is present in the first variable array and not the second then $ssh=22 .

**example -> SSH port:**

pseudo code  : first non null wins

```
ssh = { print 22 if 22 is in nsg_port_a || print 22 if 22 is on nsg_port_b}
```

I first tried to check if ssh port is open separately in the first variable. then using the coalescing logic check if the second nsg_port_b contains 22 or is null (if both are null it's fine). if it exist in any of them the value stays ssh=22.

**first check**

```
 with $nsg_port_a = 22 80 443
# ssh=$(echo $nsg_port_a | awk 'match($0,/22/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}')
# echo $ssh
22
```

**second check** I tried the below but I have syntax errors

```
 $nsg_port_b = 80 442   

 # ssh=${echo $nsg_port_b | awk 'match($0,/22/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}':-${ssh}}
-bash: ${echo $nsg_port_b | awk 'match($0,/22/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}':-${ssh}}: bad substitution
```

**Note** :

I am sure I can do the check from both variables in one line. but I can't get which syntax to use.

i.e  take the first non null value the both vars checks in a one liner.

```
ssh=${`echo $nsg_port_a | awk 'match($0,/22/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`: `echo $nsg_port_b | awk 'match($0,/22/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`}
```

thanks in advance
koss

---

**EDIT**

My bad my sample was showing the values displayed in one row (tab separated) which is right even though the content was new line separated when I ran the $(az network...) request the encapsulation of the values in the variable flattens the list to one row if I echo nsg_port_a without `"`. I am aware that 22 can be contained in port 422 but I'm only focused in popular values like 22/80/443/3389.

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in your question, keep it up. Request you to please explain logic more clearly for better understanding please.

Comment: agreed . I am building the bash script from scratch for an azure cli lab  so the logic is still evolving . I am trying to be as explicit as possible.
cheers

Comment: bash's null coalescing only works on the value of a simple variable -- that is, it's `${var:-expression}`, where the `var` part can only be a variable -- not a command or other expression. The alternate value -- the thing to the right of `:-` -- can be more complicated. But do you really need this? Why not just check whether the port number occurs in `"$nsg_port_a $nsg_port_b"`? Oh, and searching for the number can cause false matches, e.g. "22" will be found in "80 443 4220".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make whatever part of it is the sample input and whichever the expected output given that input clear as right now I can't find it among all of the text. Try to be clearer about **what** it is you want to do rather than **how** you want to do it ("null coalescing").

Comment: @EdMorton you are right . I made a little change in my question hoping it'll bring more clarity in my issue. your solution is close 
thanks again

Comment: I just noticed you say `I have two variables and they store list of ports in a vertically (Array)...` and then show `nsg_port_a=$(az network...)` which does **not** populate `nsg_port_a` as an array, it populates it as a scalar but then you showed us the output of `echo $nsg_port_a` instead of `echo "$nsg_port_a"` to show the contents of that variable and that would have converted all white space to blank chars. Is it possible that the output of `$(az network...)` is tab or newline-separated instead of blank-separated? [edit] your question to show us the output of `echo "$nsg_port_a"`

Comment: @EdMorton yes you are right  when echo without quotes I have them tab separated  instead of new line separated. I usually don't use the quotes of braces unless I have to concatenate the variable with a string.

Comment: @koss you're thinking about quotes backwards - quotes are something you must always use by default, you don't add them when you need to, you **remove** them when you need to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Braces are something different and not related to quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and good point. I just checked my scripts and almost all the variable are quoted except  for this very section . I'll make sure all vars are quoted  from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now think the problem is you don't actually have blank chars between your ports as shown in your question but instead have newlines or tabs. Given that, this will work no matter what the white space is:

```
$ nsg_port_a='22 80 443'
$ nsg_port_b='80 443'
$ [[ " $nsg_port_a $nsg_port_b " =~ [[:space:]]22[[:space:]] ]] && ssh=22
$ echo "$ssh"
22
```

Answer (score 3):

I am considering that you want to check if port `22` is present in your both variables or not, if this is what you need then please try following. Make sure your shell variables `nsg_port_a` and `nsg_port_b` are set with values since they are being passed to `awk` program further.

```
awk -v nsg_port_a="$nsg_port_a" -v nsg_port_b="$nsg_port_b" '
BEGIN{
  num1=split(nsg_port_a,arr1," ")
  num2=split(nsg_port_b,arr2," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
    if(arr1[i]=="22"){ found=1 }
  }
  for(k=1;k<=num2;k++){
    if(arr2[k]=="22"){ found++ }
  }
  if(found==2){
    print "Port 22 found in both variables."
  }
  else{
    print "Port 22 NOT found in both variables."
  }
}'
```

Adding one liner form of solution as per OP's request(though its always recommended to use non-one liner form of solution):

`awk -v nsg_port_a="$nsg_port_a" -v nsg_port_b="$nsg_port_b" 'BEGIN{num1=split(nsg_port_a,arr1," ");num2=split(nsg_port_b,arr2," ");for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){if(arr1[i]=="22"){ found=1 }};for(k=1;k<=num2;k++){if(arr2[k]=="22"){ found++ }};if(found==2){print "Port 22 found in both variables."}else{print "Port 22 NOT found in both variables."}}'`